# Complex analysis integration with contour

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration

Show that the next limit exists and finds its value
$$\lim_{R \to\infty}\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{\sin(x)}{x-3i}\ dx$$
My idea is to multiply by the conjugate in the denominator to obtain:
$$\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+9}\ dx$$
and then apply the residue theorem.

Comment: You can already apply the residue theorem to the original integral. Also, if you multiply the denominator by the conjugate you would have to so the same to the numerator..

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Write your integral as
$$
\int_{-R}^R \frac{\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix)}{2i(x-3i)}\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
So consider
$$
\int_{C_+}\frac{\exp(iz)}{(z-3i)}\,\mathrm{d}z\text{ and }\int_{C_-}\frac{\exp(-iz)}{(z-3i)}\,\mathrm{d}z
$$
where $C_+$ is an appropriate contour contour in the upper half plane, together with $[-R,R]$, and $C_-$ is an appropriate contour in the lower half plane, $0\leq t\leq\pi$ together with $[-R,R]$.  Can you see how to finish it from here?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that
$$
\int_{-R}^R \frac{\sin x}{x-3i}dx = \Re \left(3i \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+9}dx \right)+ \Im\left(
 \int_{-R}^R \frac{x e^{ix}}{x^2+9} dx\right)
$$

Let us now look to each integral on the RHS. In what follows $C_R$ denotes the arc of the circumference centered in $0$ that connects $R$ and $-R$. In both cases we have integrals of the form $\int_{C_R} f(z) e^{imz} dz$ with $m>0$ and $|f(z)| < \frac{M}{R^k}$ for some $M,k>0$ and for all $z \in C_R$. In these conditions, it can be shown that 
$$
\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_R} f(z) e^{imz} dz = 0.
$$

Hence, for $R>3$,

$$
\int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+9} dx + \int_{C_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+9} dz = 2\pi i Res(\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+9}, 3i)
$$

$$
\int_{-R}^R \frac{x e^{ix}}{x^2+9} dx + \int_{C_R} \frac{z e^{iz}}{z^2+9} dz = 2\pi i Res(\frac{z e^{iz}}{z^2+9}, 3i)
$$

Taking the limit as $R \to \infty$, since the integrals over $C_r$ will vanish, we will get

$$
\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+9} dx = 2\pi i Res(\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+9}, 3i) = \frac{\pi}{3e^3}
$$

$$
\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{-R}^R \frac{x e^{ix}}{x^2+9} dx = 2\pi i Res(\frac{z e^{iz}}{z^2+9}, 3i)=\frac{i \pi}{e^3}
$$

So, as a final result, we will obtain $\frac{\pi}{e^3}$.

Comment: But $\sin z$ grows exponentially fast along the imaginary axis, so this is not going to work.

Comment: @mrf Note the "If this is the case..." in my answer.

Comment: So you're intentionally posting a misleading answer?

Comment: @mrf No, I just posted a fast answer and did not check it in detail. It is a conditional answer, if you will. And the condition was that the second integral would go to zero, as it is usual in many such examples. But note that what you say is not obvious... Even if the absolute value of $\sin$ grows exponentially, the integral over that particular curve may behave differently.

Comment: @mrf I edited my original post. The initial calculations are not very important, they are just meant to start from your initial idea of multiplying by $(x+3i)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^R\frac{\sin(x)}{x-3i}dx=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^R\frac{(x+3i)\sin(x)}{x^2+9}dx$$
$$L=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x}{x^2+9}\sin(x)dx+3i\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+9}dx$$
and we can say that:
$$\frac{x}{x^2+9}\le\frac{1}{x}\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{1}{x^2+9}\le\frac{1}{x^2}\tag{2}$$
If we apply this we get:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x}{x^2+9}\sin(x)dx\le\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\pi\tag{3}$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+9}=0\tag{4}$$
And so we can say:
$$L\le\pi$$
so the limit exists

Comment: it is not true that $\frac{x}{x^2+9}\leq \frac 1x$. Also, the upper bound does not justify the existence of limit, nor it rules out the possibility of being $-\infty$.